# pytest fixture has unexpected result

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I'm learning pytest and as I was reading the part of the documentation that explains how [fixtures can be requested more than once per test (return values are cached)](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-can-be-requested-more-than-once-per-test-return-values-are-cached) I was wondering if the provided assertion in the example (see below) `assert order == [first_entry]` can
also be written as `assert append_first == [first_entry]`.

If I write the assertion like this it doesn't pass like the other one because append_first is None and I would like to know why it isn't ['a'] in this case since it should already have been executed.

```
# contents of test_append.py
import pytest


# Arrange
@pytest.fixture
def first_entry():
    return "a"


# Arrange
@pytest.fixture
def order():
    return []


# Act
@pytest.fixture
def append_first(order, first_entry):
    return order.append(first_entry)


def test_string_only(append_first, order, first_entry):
    # Assert 1: Pass
    assert order == [first_entry]
    
    # Assert 2: AssertionError: assert None == ['a']
    assert append_first == [first_entry]
```

Comment: `list.append` does not return a value, so the result is as expected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Is it because `order.append` has no predefined value like `"a"` or `[ ]`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "predefined value". `list.append` appends a value, but returns `None` (e.g. nothing). Your code seems to assume that it returns the list itself, which it does not, so the fixture always returns `None`.

Comment: Generally, it is bad practice though to change the return value of a fixture in a test. This would make the fixture depend on the order of the tests, which quite error-prone and not what fixtures are for. Returning a changed _copy_ of the list would be fine.

Comment: I got it now. As you said I assumed that list.append returns the list after the new element got appended. Thank you very much.